# POJO breaks Dependency Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Independently of the DI Framework used - a single POJO within the object chain always breaks the DI mechanism.

Pseudocode example:

```
class A {
    @Inject
    private B b;
}

class B {
    private C c=new C();

}

class C {
    @Inject
    private D d;
}
```

The injection in class C won't work, as the `new C()` in class B breaks the chain of managed objects.

We are currently trying to improve our old (non-DI) project by incrementally replacing manual object creation with DI mechanisms.

So how to migrate `C` to DI, without even caring about `A` and `B`?

Comment: You are already doing something to achieve DI right? What are you doing?

Comment: why can't you @inject private C; if you creating instance with "new"  DI injection of course no longer works

Comment: @kuhajeyan Of course it does not. But my question is if there is some strategy to migrate step by step (beginning with C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with keeping the direct calls to the constructor (without bytecode manipulation).

Here is a way to semi-automatically refactor your code to what you might need.

The usual IDE lets you create/refactory factory methods out of constructors. With doing that refactoring all calls to `new C()` will be transformed to `C.createInstance()` (or whatever the factory method is called).

Afterwards change the factory method to actually resolve the C from your dependency injection framework.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you don't want to inject the `C` you call your container to resolve `C`:

```
C c = container.resolve(C.class);
```

or you let the `C` also be injected e.g. when calling the constructor

or like you did before:

```
@Inject
private C c;
```

Here are is some example code for `CDI`:

https://jaxenter.de/cdi-geht-fremd-dependency-injection-fur-javase-5039

The resolve the needed object by using:

> `UpdateCustomerController controller = (Controller) BeanProvider.getContextualReference("updateController", false);`

Comment: But my "old code" (the lines I do not want to touch) _does_ use `new C()`. So I need a way to inject to C, without touching the creation of C

Comment: If you want to partly go ahead of refactoring you can let the `C` be like it is and you only change the class `C` code like in your example. Without touching than you use. What kind of dependency injection are you using?

Comment: @k_wave if you don't want to touch the creation of `C` you can use the given code above and let `D` be created from the container within the constructor from `C`.